# Install libgtk2.0-0:i386 dependency problems

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm trying to install libgtk2.0-0:i386 to solve this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I try `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386`, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libatk1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.32.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.41.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpango-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to use aptitude instead as I've seen suggested elsewhere,

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libatk1.0-0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libcairo2:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libdatrie1:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} 
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{ab} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgraphite2-3:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386{a} libhogweed4:i386{a} libidn11:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} 
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} libnettle6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpango-1.0-0:i386{a} libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libthai0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcb-shm0:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} 
  libxrender1:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 43 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,693 kB of archives. After unpacking 25.4 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.48.2-0ubuntu1+elementary0.4.1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.48.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu1+elementary0.4.1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libatk1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                   
2)     libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]            
3)     libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                  
4)     libgtk2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                   
5)     libharfbuzz0b:i386 [Not Installed]                 
6)     libpango-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                
7)     libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]           
8)     libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]             



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Which doesn't actually do anything.  All the other proposed solutions involve removing a large number of fundamental packages (like elementary-desktop).

If it helps, the output of `sudo apt-get update` is

```
Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                                   
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                     
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                               
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease                              
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17.6 kB]
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  404  Not Found
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Fetched 120 kB in 4s (28.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm fairly sure the error there isn't related but if anyone has any clues as to what's going on there that would also be great.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a i386 library in a 64 bits OS?

Comment: it's for a game

Comment: What's the game?